# Append a dictionary to a dictionary no overide

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

```
dic1 ={'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3}
dic2 ={'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3}
```

become:

```
data ={ {'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3}, {'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3}}
```

Comment: so you want a list/set of a dict?

Comment: `data = (dic1, dic2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hash a dictionary, so creating a `set` of dictionaries is not possible.

Try creating a `tuple` or `list` instead:

```
>>> dic1 = {'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3}
>>> dic2 = {'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3}
>>> data = (dic1, dic2)
>>> data
({'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3}, {'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3})
>>> data = [dic1, dic2]
>>> data
[{'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3}, {'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3}]
```

Alternatively, you could utilize [`immutabledict`](https://pypi.org/project/immutabledict/):

```
>>> from immutabledict import immutabledict
>>> data = {immutabledict(dic1), immutabledict(dic2)}
>>> data
{immutabledict({'materials_id': 4, 'name': 'chemistry', 'capacity': 3}), immutabledict({'materials_id': 5, 'name': 'paint', 'capacity': 3})}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this different way

```
Data = { 'materials_id': id_indexlist[0] , 

         'name' : names_list[0], ... 
        
        }
```

Instead using a dictionary inside another dictionary, try combine a dictionary with several lists.